# Function is not defined (even though it is)

Tags: javascript, function, reactjs, undefined

I call this function inside a .then promise

```
this.retrieveMatches();
```

this function looks like the following

```
retrieveMatches: function(){
    var tableResult = makeHTMLMatchesTable(fetchMatches());
    var matches = document.getElementById('matches')
    matches.parentNode.insertBefore(tableResult, matches);
  },
```

this function is just above it:

```
 makeHTMLMatchesTable: function(array){
    //does stuff
    }
```

so why does the console say this:

`Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: makeHTMLMatchesTable is not defined`

when it clearly has been defined?

Comment: Erm, you aren't calling it with `this`.

Comment: You should include the closures where everything is defined

Comment: @Mayday What do you mean by "closures"?

Comment: This question needs more context: please provide the code in one block, so it is visible how the different objects relate to each other in terms of context and scope.

Comment: @tricot Actually it's quite clear what the problem is: it is as the comment from vlaz. This question should be closed as a typo and we all move on.

Comment: Look closely at the wording you yourself used in the title: **function is not defined**. However, the way you define it (`makeHTMLMatchesTable: function(...`) it is a **method**.

Comment: ditzy sunday morn moment apparently :/ cheers tho folks.
not sure why it wont render the table now but we will keep looking!

Answer (score 0):

Change this code

```
retrieveMatches: function(){
    var tableResult = makeHTMLMatchesTable(fetchMatches());
    var matches = document.getElementById('matches')
    matches.parentNode.insertBefore(tableResult, matches);
  },
```

to

```
retrieveMatches: function(){
    var tableResult = this.makeHTMLMatchesTable(fetchMatches());
    var matches = document.getElementById('matches')
    matches.parentNode.insertBefore(tableResult, matches);
  }.bind(this),
```